# Find the word after the pattern using Awk

Tags: awk, grep, find

I have executed the below command and i have stored the data in sample.txt file.

```
chkconfig --list | grep postfix > sample.txt
```

Now this file contains the below output :

```
postfix         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Now I need to extract the string after `2:`. The output should be `on`

Is the anyway we can find it using `awk` or `grep`?

Comment: try `....|grep -Po '(?<=2:)\w+'`

Comment: @Kent Will match `22:` too, probably a space before `2` should suffice

Comment: Or any non-digit character.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk` bypassing the temp file creation if extraction is the only purpose of the temp file:

```
chkconfig --list | awk '/postfix/{$0=substr($4,3)}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

awk can do that:

```
 awk -F '[: ]+' '{print $7}'
```

Also you don't need a grep. Following awk will do the job:

```
chkconfig --list | awk -F '[: ]+' '$1 == "postfix" {print $7}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But still  i could not get the result. My requirement is , I have output in " sample.txt " file. I want to grep the status of "2:" , which is '"on". Can you please provide me the solution for this.

Comment: Above awk command will give you `on` as output which is next to `2:`. Are you not getting same output?

Comment: Solution is technically correct. Perhaps consider dividing into two steps. Here's a slight variation based on the same theme: `chkconfig --list | awk '/^postfix[[:space:]]/{print $4}' | cut -f1 -d':'`

Comment: Dilip: If you need to pick up the result from a specific intermediate file, just pick it up with cat. If pre-filtered (as in you example), you also skip the `$1 == "postfix"`part. I.e. final solution shoud be `cat sample.txt | awk -F '[: ]+' '{print $7}'`

Comment: Hi Michael Ambrus. Thank you very much for you comments. That makes sense. I could resolve this with your comments. Thanks once again.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.